How to update a data from a hashmap that's in different classes?
I tried to access my hashmap classes in order to retrieve the data I inputted in from my from the hashmap classes classes. Here's my updated button for accessing the Hashmaps.
public class WelcomePage {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JButton logoutButton = new JButton("Logout");
    JLabel welcomeLabel = new JLabel("Hello!");
    JButton printInfoButton = new JButton("Print Information");
    JButton UpdateInfoButton = new JButton("Update Info");
    JButton SALARYButton = new JButton("Salary");
    JButton AttendanceButton = new JButton("Attendance");
    JButton leaveManagementButton = new JButton("Leave Management");


    HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> timeRecords = new HashMap<>();
    SalaryStorage salaryStorage = new SalaryStorage();
    IDandPasswords idAndPasswords = new IDandPasswords();
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<Leave>> leaveRecords = new HashMap<>();

    WelcomePage(String userID) {

        welcomeLabel.setBounds(0, 0, 200, 35);
        welcomeLabel.setFont(new Font(null, Font.PLAIN, 25));
        welcomeLabel.setText("Hello " +userID);

        logoutButton.setBounds(300, 300, 100, 25);
        logoutButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                frame.dispose();
            }
        });


        SALARYButton.setBounds(100, 100, 200, 25);
        SALARYButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // Ask for work hours
                String workHoursInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Enter work hours:");
                if (workHoursInput == null || workHoursInput.isEmpty()) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Please enter valid work hours!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    return;
                }

                double workHours = Double.parseDouble(workHoursInput);

                // Check if there's overtime
                String overtimeHoursInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Do you have overtime hours? (Enter 0 if no)");
                double overtimeHours = Double.parseDouble(overtimeHoursInput);

                // Calculate salary details
                double basicSalary = workHours * 400; // Assuming basic salary rate is $10 per hour
                double overtimePay = 0;
                if (overtimeHours > 0) {
                    overtimePay = overtimeHours * 600; // Assuming overtime rate is $15 per hour
                }

                double grossPay = basicSalary + overtimePay;
                double taxes = grossPay * 0.14 * 0.04 * 4.5; // Assuming 20% tax rate
                double netPay = grossPay - taxes;

                // Display salary details
                String message;
                if (overtimeHours > 0) {
                    message = "Regular Work Hours: " + workHours + "\n"
                            + "Overtime Hours: " + overtimeHours + "\n"
                            + "Gross Pay: ₱" + grossPay + "\n"
                            + "Taxes: ₱" + taxes + "\n"
                            + "Net Pay: ₱ " + netPay;
                } else {
                    message = "Regular Work Hours: " + workHours + "\n"
                            + "Gross Pay: ₱" + grossPay + "\n"
                            + "Taxes: ₱" + taxes + "\n"
                            + "Net Pay: ₱" + netPay;
                }
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, message, "Salary Details", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

                // Save salary details using SalaryStorage
                salaryStorage.addSalaryInfo(userID, grossPay, taxes, netPay, overtimePay);
            }
        });
        AttendanceButton.setBounds(100, 140, 200, 25);
        AttendanceButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // Show option dialog to choose between time in and time out
                String[] options = {"Time In", "Time Out"};
                int choice = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame, "Choose an option:", "Time Recorder", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION,
                        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);

                if (choice == 0) { // Time In
                    TimeRecorder.recordTimeIn(timeRecords, frame);
                } else if (choice == 1) { // Time Out
                    TimeRecorder.recordTimeOut(timeRecords, frame);
                } else { // User closed the dialog or clicked outside
                    System.out.println("No option selected.");
                }
            }
        });
        UpdateInfoButton.setBounds(100, 180, 200, 25);
        UpdateInfoButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // Ask for User ID
                String userID = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Enter User ID:");
                if (userID != null && !userID.isEmpty()) {
                    // Check if the User ID exists and is valid
                    if (idAndPasswords.isValidUserId(userID)) {
                        // If User ID is valid, proceed with updating user information
                        String newFirstName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Enter new first name:");
                        String newLastName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Enter new last name:");
                        String newPassword = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Enter new password:");
                        if (newFirstName != null && newLastName != null && newPassword != null &&
                                !newFirstName.isEmpty() && !newLastName.isEmpty() && !newPassword.isEmpty()) {
                            // Update user information
                            idAndPasswords.updateUserInfo(userID, newFirstName, newLastName, newPassword);
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "User information updated successfully!", "Success", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                        } else {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Please enter valid information!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        }
                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Invalid User ID!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "User ID cannot be empty!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
        });
        printInfoButton.setBounds(100, 220, 200, 25); // Position and size of the new button
        printInfoButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                StringBuilder infoBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                // Append user information
                IDandPasswords.UserInfo userInfo = idAndPasswords.getLoginInfo().get(userID);
                if (userInfo != null) {
                    infoBuilder.append("User Information:\n");
                    infoBuilder.append("User ID: ").append(userID).append("\n");
                    infoBuilder.append("First Name: ").append(userInfo.getFirstName()).append("\n");
                    infoBuilder.append("Last Name: ").append(userInfo.getLastName()).append("\n");

                    // Append salary information
                    SalaryStorage.SalaryInfo salaryInfo = salaryStorage.getSalaryMap().get(userID);
                    if (salaryInfo != null) {
                        infoBuilder.append("\nSalary Information:\n");
                        infoBuilder.append("Gross Pay: $").append(salaryInfo.getGrossPay()).append("\n");
                        infoBuilder.append("Taxes: $").append(salaryInfo.getTaxes()).append("\n");
                        infoBuilder.append("Net Pay: $").append(salaryInfo.getNetPay()).append("\n");
                        infoBuilder.append("Overtime Pay: $").append(salaryInfo.getOvertimePay()).append("\n");
                    }

                    // Append time records
                    if (timeRecords.containsKey(userID)) {
                        ArrayList<String> records = timeRecords.get(userID);
                        infoBuilder.append("\nTime Records:\n");
                        for (String record : records) {
                            infoBuilder.append(record).append("\n");
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    // Handle case where user ID doesn't exist
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "User ID not found!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }

                // Print the information
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, infoBuilder.toString(), "User Information", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
        });
        leaveManagementButton.setBounds(100, 260, 200, 25); // Position and size of the new button
        leaveManagementButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String[] options = {"Maternal Leave", "Sick Leave", "Vacation Leave"};
                String selectedOption = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Choose a leave type:",
                        "Leave Management", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);

                if (selectedOption != null) {
                    int maxLeaves = 10; // Example maximum limit of leaves
                    String leaveDaysInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Enter number of days for " + selectedOption + " (max " + maxLeaves + " days):");
                    if (leaveDaysInput != null && !leaveDaysInput.isEmpty()) {
                        int leaveDays = Integer.parseInt(leaveDaysInput);
                        if (leaveDays > 0 && leaveDays <= maxLeaves) {
                            // Logic to handle leave request
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Leave requested successfully!", "Success", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                        } else {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Invalid number of days or exceeds maximum limit!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        }
                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Please enter valid number of days!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        frame.add(welcomeLabel);
        frame.add(logoutButton);
        frame.add(UpdateInfoButton);
        frame.add(SALARYButton);
        frame.add(AttendanceButton);
        frame.add(printInfoButton);
        frame.add(leaveManagementButton);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(420, 420);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            IDandPasswords idAndPasswords = new IDandPasswords();
            // Retrieve necessary data from WelcomePage, SalaryStorage, IDandPasswords
            HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> timeRecords = new HashMap<>();
            SalaryStorage salaryStorage = new SalaryStorage();
            Map<String, IDandPasswords.UserInfo> loginInfo = idAndPasswords.getLoginInfo();
            // Create an instance of InformationPrinter with the extracted data

        });
    }
}

Whenever I try to click the button, it would prompt me to username not found, but whenever I tried to input the population that I inputted from my hashmaps it would lead me to print the information that I entered in. I think my hasmap isn't being overwritten. Here's the code for my Hashmaps for ID, Firstname, Lastname, and password.
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;



public class IDandPasswords {

    private HashMap<String, UserInfo> logininfo = new HashMap<>();

    public IDandPasswords() {
        // Populate logininfo
        logininfo.put("Justine", new UserInfo("Cute", "Realubit", "pizza"));
        logininfo.put("Kacey", new UserInfo("Cute", "Gutierrez", "PASSWORD"));
        logininfo.put("Joshua", new UserInfo("Cute", "Santos", "abc123"));
    }

    public boolean isValidUserId(String userId) {
        return logininfo.containsKey(userId);
    }

    // Method to update user information
    public void updateUserInfo(String userId, String newFirstName, String newLastName, String newPassword) {
        UserInfo user = logininfo.get(userId);
        if (user != null) {
            user.setFirstName(newFirstName);
            user.setLastName(newLastName);
            user.setPassword(newPassword);
        } else {
            System.out.println("User not found!");
        }
    }

    public Map<String, UserInfo> getLoginInfo() {
        return logininfo;
    }

    public static class UserInfo {
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private String password;

        public UserInfo(String firstName, String lastName, String password) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.password = password;
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }
    }
}

In my LogIn Page
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Signup extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JTextField usernameField;
    private JPasswordField passwordField;
    private JButton signupButton;
    private UserInfo[] users;
    private int userCount;

    Signup(UserInfo[] users, int userCount) {
        super("Signup");
        this.users = users;
        this.userCount = userCount;

        setSize(300, 150);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Center the frame
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 2));

        panel.add(new JLabel("Username:"));
        usernameField = new JTextField();
        panel.add(usernameField);

        panel.add(new JLabel("Password:"));
        passwordField = new JPasswordField();
        panel.add(passwordField);

        signupButton = new JButton("Sign Up");
        signupButton.addActionListener(this);
        panel.add(signupButton);

        getContentPane().add(panel);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String username = usernameField.getText();
        char[] password = passwordField.getPassword();

        // Add user to the array
        users[userCount] = new UserInfo(username, password);
        userCount++; // Increment user count

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User Signed Up Successfully!");

        // Dispose of the signup window
        dispose();
        // Open the login page again
        new LoginPage();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UserInfo[] users = new UserInfo[10]; // Initialize the array with a fixed size
        int userCount = 0;

        // Start the signup process
        new Signup(users, userCount);
    }
} ```



Hello @vanai There is no problem with the code as of the information shared. Please verify your application code populating the data, what is value for userID?

Hello! I edited it out, and included the application code.

Personal and opinioned design critique: don't expose your Map<K, V> (e.g. IDandPasswords#getLoginInfo), instead offer the functionality you want (e.g. V get(K key) { return privateMap.get(key); }). This enables you to encapsulate the map, in addition to making your design around the objects themselves (vs. code that just eventually plays hot potato with a lot of maps).

For the issue at hand: show the code surrounding your first snippet. Where that idAndPasswords variable came from and how it is used elsewheres matters.

Got it! I edited it out, and entered the surrounding code on the snippet.

Note that hashmap keys are case-sensitive, are you entering the correct casing for the username (e.g. Justine, not justine)? Are you testing using the #main in WelcomePage? I'm not seeing how WelcomePage is being made, but the idAndPasswords in that method is distinct from the idAndPasswords field inside of WelcomePage. Having the same name doesn't make them the same variable, context matters. If SalaryStorage creates WelcomePage, then you've got a cyclic dependency.

(Also show the code for your Login page)

Hello! I updated the post and wrote the LogInPage code.

You create an instance of class IDandPasswords in class WelcomePage:
IDandPasswords idAndPasswords = new IDandPasswords();

You update an instance of class IDandPasswords in your LogIn Page. (I assume LogIn Page is another class.)
loginInfo.put(userID, new IDandPasswords.UserInfo(firstName, lastName, password));

I also assume that loginInfo is an instance of IDandPasswords.
Therefore, variable idAndPasswords, in class WelcomePage is not referring to the same instance that variable loginInfo is and that's why you never find the details in idAndPasswords that you updated in loginInfo.
You need to pass loginInfo to class WelcomePage. If you create an instance of WelcomePage from class LogIn Page, then maybe add a parameter to the constructor of WelcomePage, e.g.
WelcomePage(String userID, IDandPasswords idAndPasswords) {
    this.idAndPasswords = idAndPasswords;
}

Alternatively, maybe make class IDandPasswords a singleton or make that class's logininfo attribute static and, subsequently, make the methods static.
(Below code uses a static initializer.)
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class IDandPasswords {

    private static Map<String, UserInfo> logininfo = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        // Populate logininfo
        logininfo.put("Justine", new UserInfo("Cute", "Realubit", "pizza"));
        logininfo.put("Kacey", new UserInfo("Cute", "Gutierrez", "PASSWORD"));
        logininfo.put("Joshua", new UserInfo("Cute", "Santos", "abc123"));
    }

    public static boolean isValidUserId(String userId) {
        return logininfo.containsKey(userId);
    }

    // Method to update user information
    public static void updateUserInfo(String userId,
                                      String newFirstName,
                                      String newLastName,
                                      String newPassword) {
        UserInfo user = logininfo.get(userId);
        if (user != null) {
            user.setFirstName(newFirstName);
            user.setLastName(newLastName);
            user.setPassword(newPassword);
        } else {
            System.out.println("User not found!");
        }
    }

    public static Map<String, UserInfo> getLoginInfo() {
        return logininfo;
    }

    public static class UserInfo {
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private String password;

        public UserInfo(String firstName, String lastName, String password) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.password = password;
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }
    }
}

Then you will always be accessing and modifying the same IDandPasswords object.
